# Bootstrap 5 navbar toggle not showing on fixed-top

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, toggle, navbar, bootstrap-5

I'm using the Bootstrap 5 navbar fixed at the top and the toggle doesn't show when resizing the browser. When I remove the fixed top I can see the toggle. What am I missing?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Name</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="`enter code here`">Resume</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Linkedin</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">GitHub</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Email</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

putting back the original

```
navbar-dark bg-dark
```

will bring back the toggle when resizing the page. I feel like this is so simple and I'm so close.

Comment: what do you mean when you say "the toggle doesn't show when resizing"? the toggle it's all navbar? or menu items?

Comment: and after what screen resolution it disappears?

Comment: @likquietly I was referring to the three lined "hamburger menu". the resolution it disappeared at was after 991px length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I changed

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
```

to

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-transparent fixed-top">
```

Adding the `navbar-dark bg-transparent` brought the toggle back.